# command to delete folders older than 10 days in Windows 7 with exceptions

Tags: windows, cmd

I need to delete folders in a specific directory which weren't modified for more than 30 days. So I have this below command which works perfectly:

```
FORFILES /S /D -30 /C "cmd /c IF @isdir == TRUE rd /S /Q @path"
```

My question is how do I exclude a specific folder called "DoNotDelete" when running this command?

Comment: Um, add another `if`? It's just programming.

Answer (score 0):

Check for the name of the directory to be omitted. When you are confident that only the correct directories will be removed, delete the `echo` from the `rd` command.

```
FORFILES /S /D -30 /C ^
    "cmd /c IF @isdir == TRUE (IF /I @file NEQ DoNotDelete (echo rd /S /Q @path))"
```